# How to make an apple fall from the top of the screen?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I am trying to make an apple falls from the top of the screen to the the bottom. I found the below solution which works fine. but there is only one problem if I change the variable changingY to   `localCoordinates2.getY()` the apple does not move any more, So how can I make the apple falls fall down ?

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(localGoodApple.getGraphic(), localCoordinates2.getX(),changingY, null);
    if(changingY < canvas.getHeight() ) {
        changingY +=10; // The changingY is a field of type integer 
    }else
    {
        changingY = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Because if you change it to localCoordinates2.getY() - drawBitmap() draws your image in position that returned by localCoordinates2.getY() => but localCoordinates2.getY() every time returns the same position.

Comment: I thought using `localCoordinates2.getY() ` will help me to implement the method detect collision between two objects. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change changingY to localCoordinates2.getY() the apple will not move because getY() is just returning the value of whatever the y is on localCoordinates2, but not the reference, so any changes you make to getY() won't actually change the y.

Change your code to this(assuming setY is a method):

```
canvas.drawBitmap(localGoodApple.getGraphic(), localCoordinates2.getX(), localCoordinates2.getY(), null);
if(localCoordinates2.getY() < canvas.getHeight() ) {
    localCoordinates2.setY(localCoordinates2.getY() + 10);
} else
{
    localCoordinates2.setY(0);
}
```